# How do I change this sql query to Magento2 filter collection method?

Tags: magento2, collection, newsletter, query

I have below query

```
SELECT * FROM newsletter_subscriber WHERE change_status_at >=  (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 DAY);
```

How do I make it works with below?

```
        public function  getSubscriberStatus()
    {
        

        $subscriberCollectionData =$this->subscriberCollection->create();

/***********************query where cause **************************/
        


        foreach($subscriberCollectionData as $subscriber)
{
    print_r($subscriber->getData());
}

        return $subscriberCollectionData;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

by answer my own question

```
    public function  getSubscriberStatus()
{
    

    $subscriberCollectionData =$this->subscriberCollection->create();
    $subscriberCollectionData->getSelect()
                ->where(
            'change_status_at >= ?',
            $subscriberCollectionData->getConnection()->getDateSubSql(
                new Zend_Db_Expr('NOW()'),
                '30',
                AdapterInterface::INTERVAL_MINUTE
            )
        );

    return $subscriberCollectionData;
}
```